# drag and drop: NSView thinks source is an image that it isn't

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, nsimage, nsimageview

I have two views.
1. One view has a grid of NSImageViews with images.
2. The other view has a grid of potential places to place the dragged image.

I think I have dragging working. If I click and drag an image from view 1, it works fine, but when I try to place it, the path of the source image is for an image on my desktop that isn't even part of my project. The result of the below code is that carriedData = nil, but I did some testing with NSLog and saw that it is sending the path for an image outside the project that is no my desktop.

Here is some of the D&D protocol methods I have implemented. myDragState is just en enumeration I use for highlighting the grid space that the drag is currently hovering over.

in Init...

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSImage imagePasteboardTypes]];
myDragState = dragStateNone;
```

Then the protocol methods

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{

    if ((NSDragOperationGeneric & [sender draggingSourceOperationMask]) == NSDragOperationGeneric)
    {
        myDragState = dragStateOver;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

        return NSDragOperationGeneric;
    }
    else
    {
        return NSDragOperationNone;
    }
}

- (void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    //turn off focus ring
    myDragState = dragStateExited;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)draggingEnded:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender { }

- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSPasteboard *paste = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    //gets the dragging-specific pasteboard from the sender
    NSArray *types = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSTIFFPboardType, nil];
    //a list of types that we can accept
    NSString *desiredType = [paste availableTypeFromArray:types];
    NSData *carriedData = [paste dataForType:desiredType];

    if (nil == carriedData)
    {
        //the operation failed for some reason
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Paste Error", @"Sorry, but the past operation failed", nil, nil, nil);

        myDragState = dragStateNone;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        //the pasteboard was able to give us some meaningful data
        if ([desiredType isEqualToString:NSTIFFPboardType])
        {
            NSLog(@"TIFF");
            //we have TIFF bitmap data in the NSData object
            NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:carriedData];
            [self setImage:newImage];

            myDragState = dragStateSet;
        }
        else
        {
            //this can't happen
            //NSAssert(NO, @"This can't happen");
            NSLog(@"Other type");
            myDragState = dragStateNone;
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    //redraw us with the new image
    return YES;
}

- (void)concludeDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    //re-draw the view with our new data
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
    NSRect ourBounds = [self bounds];

    if (myDragState == dragStateSet)
    {
        NSImage *image = [self image];
        [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
        [image compositeToPoint:(ourBounds.origin) operation:NSCompositeSourceOver];
    }
    else if (myDragState == dragStateOver)
    {
        [[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.4f] set];
        [NSBezierPath fillRect:ourBounds];
    }
    else {
        //draw nothing
    }

}
```

Edit: So I figured this out. The problem was actually with the source. I wasn't copying it to the PBoard properly. My code for that is:

```
NSPasteboard *zPasteBoard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard]; 
[zPasteBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSTIFFPboardType] owner:self]; 
[zPasteBoard setData:[tileImageView.image TIFFRepresentation] forType:NSTIFFPboardType];
```

Now I am getting some weird effect when the images show though. As the images are placed in the destination imageview, they are being resized, but the larger draggable version is also still showing up. So, I am getting two images on the image view.

Comment: You say you want the image source but it looks like you are pasting the image data?

Comment: So, I changed it to just paste the image name string based on the dropped image and I am still getting this weird double image behavior

Comment: So, with more tinkering, I have it properly placing the image the way I want it, but it is resizing the source to the size of the new image when I drop it. What I don't understand is that I am only passing the imagename string on the pboard and then creating a new image, so why is the source also being resized